# selenium chromedriver headless doesnt work python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import winsound
import datetime


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\QP\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") # add your chrome profile path (you can find it with texting )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options) # Add your chrome-driver path

buyingStatus = True

while(buyingStatus):
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.tr/Gelecekten-Beklentiler-Mihail-Bulgakov/dp/9750748069/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=4uywe&pf_rd_p=d2101752-dfb1-4d92-b52a-6bce600e8359&pf_rd_r=CYW70Q65WWBV7G8GKQF6&pd_rd_r=f7a95eb9-4a17-4f44-ba76-b99d7ebdcd23&pd_rd_wg=xCwst&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_d")
        print(driver.title)
        beGreedy = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('quantity'))
        beGreedy.select_by_value('2')
        addCart = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-stack").submit()
        completeTheShopping = driver.find_element_by_id("hlb-ptc-btn-native").click()
        

        buyNow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/span/input").click() 
        b = datetime.datetime.now()
        print((b-a).seconds )
        freq = 500
        dur = 2000
        winsound.Beep(freq, dur)
        print("ITEM FOUND")
        buyingStatus = False


    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Item doesn't exist")
        driver.refresh()
```

Hi guys have a good day.I try to make a bot to auto order from amazon but it doesnt work with headless mode.Console gives "Amazon.com.tr" and "Item doesn't work" over and over again untill i stop program.I guess code lines doesnt work after print(driver.title).It works very well without headless mode.I tried everything written on the internet but none of them work.Finally i am open to all ideas that will speed up the bot.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB is it better ?